# TFS Sparse checkout local workspace

Tags: tfs, workspace

Is there a way to "sparsely checkout" a local workspace in TFS 2012? We currently use SVN and are investigating TFS 2012. Specifically, I don't want my entire collection to be downloaded to a developer machine. We branch to provide isolation among teams and products. I'm hoping that we can selectively choose which items in the branch are downloaded locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map various parts of your source tree using different workspaces to achieve some of the effect that you're looking for. We use this to separate components in our build system. Workspaces are configured by client machine/by user.